# How can I use sed to regex string and number in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, separator

I want to separate string and number in a file to get a specific number in bash script, such as:

> Branches executed:75.38% of 1190

I want to only get number

> 75.38

. I have try like the code below

```
$new_value=value | sed -r 's/.*_([0-9]*)\..*/\1/g'
```

but it was incorrect and it was failed.

How should it works? Thank you before for your help.

Comment: `it was failed.` How, what did you expect and what did you get ?

Comment: I want to get value from a file that contains string and number. For example there is a file that contains "Branches executed:75.38% of 1190", then I want get value "75.38" from the file. I have tried to use this "$new_value=value | sed -r 's/.*_([0-9]*)\..*/\1/g" but it not works. So I ask for help to use sed to regex the file. That's what I expected and get. Thank you before

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to extract the first number in a line:

```
^[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\).*$
```

Usage:

```
% echo 'Branches executed:75.38% of 1190' | sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\).*$/\1/'
75.38
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
value=$(sed "s/^Branches executed:\([0-9][.0-9]*[0-9]*\)%.*$/\1/" afile)
```

It is assumed that the line appears only once in **afile**.

The value is stored in the **value** variable.

Comment: Not keen on this regex...   the last `[0-9]*` is redundant (it would be captured by the preceding `[.0-9]*`.   This will match numbers with multiple decimals (i.e. `78.6.5.4...`).   It also assumes that the preceding text is an exact string, as opposed to capturing the first number in the line, which I don't believe is the OP's intent (I could be wrong though).

Comment: true! The last digit would be capture with the preceding one char pattern, but it is a digit only, excluding string with a final **.**

Answer (score 0):

There are several things here that we could improve. One is that you need to escape the parentheses in sed: `\(...\)`

Another one is that it would be good to have a full specification of the input strings as well as a good script that can help us to play with this.

Anyway, this is my first attempt:
**Update:** I added a little more bash around this regex so it'll be more easy to play with it:

```
value='Branches executed:75.38% of 1190'
new_value=`echo $value | sed -e 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*/\1/g'`
echo $new_value
```

**Update 2:** as [john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228628/john) pointed out, it will match only numbers that contain a decimal dot. We can fix it with an optional group: `\(\.[0-9]\+\)?`.
An explanation for the optional group:

- `\(...\)` is a group.
- `\(...\)?` Is a group that appears zero or one times (mind the question mark).
- `\.[0-9]\+` is the pattern for a dot and one or more digits.

Putting all together:

```
value='Branches executed:75.38% of 1190'
new_value=`echo $value | sed -e 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\?\).*/\1/g'`
echo $new_value
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like the OP is overly familiar with sed, so a brief explanation:  The `[^0-9]*` means match all characters that are NOT in the 0-9 range (starting a range with `^` means match anything but).   This will stop consuming characters when it hits the first digit.  The `\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)` matches any number with a single decimal place, and stores it in `\1` (it will not match numbers without a decimal though...).  The `.*` matches the rest of the characters to the end of the line.